# Is there any corpus for technical English? (E.g., computers, IT, modern technology)

Tags: corpora, resource-request

Alternatively, do any larger corpora have categories that pertain to technology, computer science, etc.? Or collections of English documentation and/or manuals related to modern devices, interfaces, technology products, etc.?

Answer (score 5):

Ironically, your best bet is: https://archive.org/download/stackexchange

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are such corpora. One freely availble corpus is [IULA Spanish-English Technical Corpus](http://hdl.handle.net/10230/20052) from Universitat Pompeu Fabra.

Another one, concentrating on Computational Linguistcs, is the [ACL anthology](http://acl-arc.comp.nus.edu.sg/)

There is special search interface for language resources like corpora at [the Virtual Language Observatory (VLO)](http://vlo.clarin.eu) provided by the European [CLARIN](https://www.clarin.eu/) consortium.